# Android: Refresh an activity

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I've just a little question (I hope it's just a little question ;-)).

My current app-project has, of course, a bunch of activities. In one of these activities (I call it DataActivity) I can enter some informationen (stored on a webserver). Another activity (called ListViewActivity) should show all available information stored onto the webserver.

The problem is: My first step is to open the ListViewActivity with a few entries (it works proper at first time). Then I go to the DataActivity to input a new listitem. When I now go back to my ListViewActivity the new entry isn't listed. I think I have to refresh the ListViewActivity ... but I don't exactly know how. ;-)

What can I do to refresh this ListView after adding the new row/listitem, so that all available information will be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are calling the init of the list in onCreate.  Just implement onResume (or onStart should work as well) and add a refresh() method that recalls the data from your server for your list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) or [`notifyDataSetInvalidated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated%28%29) of your list adapter when you are back to your `ListViewActivity`.